# When I'm using Firefox browser I get an error this error is "SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message:

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6XXc.png)
This image about the Firefox error that I getting.

I want to resolve this query. Because I'm suffering this problem from day before yesterday. As much as possible please tell me how I can resolve this error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.